# Show car brand in option from mysql if any car of this brand is available

Tags: php, html, mysql

In  need to show only those car brands that are already in DB. I'm not very good in Back End. Need your help :) thanks.

If there is no BMW car in DB don't show BMW in brands. One more request if there is any BMW car so show BMW brand and show total how many cars are in BMW brand.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 option-item">
    <select data-placeholder="gege" class="form-control brand"  class="form-select brand" aria-label="Default select example" name="brand_id" style="height: 40px;">
        <?php
        $statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_car WHERE brand_id!=0");
        $statement2->execute();
        $result2 = $statement2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result2 as $row2)
        {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_brand WHERE brand_id=? ORDER BY brand_name ASC");
            $statement->execute($row2['brand_id']);
            $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                
                $statement2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_car WHERE brand_id!=0");
                $statement2->execute();
                $result2 = $statement2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($result2 as $row2)
                {
                        $brand_available = count($result2);

            ?>
            
            <option></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['brand_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['brand_name'].' current brand has '.$brand_available.' cars.'; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
        }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_brand` (
  `brand_id` tinyint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_model` (
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`model_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=416 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_car` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: So the way you are counting the $brand_available variable seems very inefficient, but aside from that you really just need to have conditional to only display something where the value of $brand_available is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well. First try to get all car brands present in the DB using a SELECT DISTINCT query. Then for each brand you need to check if there are any cars associated with that brand. If there are cars, display the make and total number of cars. Otherwise, do not show the mark.

I couldn't simulate it here, but try to do it like this, if it doesn't work I'll try another approach. Sorry about my English

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 option-item">
      <select name="brand_id" class="form-control brand-select" aria-label="Select example">
        <?php
          // Query to get all distinct brands from tbl_brand
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT b.brand_id, b.brand_name FROM tbl_brand b JOIN tbl_car c ON b.brand_id = c.brand_id ORDER BY b.brand_name ASC");
          $stmt->execute();
          $brands = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
          foreach ($brands as $brand) {
            // Query to get the count of cars for this brand
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_car WHERE brand_id = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$brand['brand_id']]);
            $count = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['count'];
    
            if ($count > 0) {
              // Display the brand and count of cars
              echo "<option value='{$brand['brand_id']}'>{$brand['brand_name']} ({$count} cars)</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks. Can you please do same to model? This code looks too much complicated for me. :D